# Unable to reference a color attribute in a drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-theme, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to create a custom set of colors, to further reference them throughout a theme.

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994091/how-to-reference-colour-attribute-in-drawable) and by following those steps, I'm trying to define `holo_blue_dark` as the custom color:

res\values\attrs.xml

```
<attr name="holo_blue_dark" format="reference|color" />
```

res\values\styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="holo_blue_dark">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

res\values\colors.xml

```
<color name="holo_blue_dark">#FF33B5E5</color>
```

I always get `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_THEME_AAPT_ERROR]` in Android Studio 0.8.2, so I must be missing something.

Comment: try <color name="holo_blue_dark">@color/theme_accent</color>

Comment: It doesn't work, I am already using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**res\values\attrs.xml**

```
<attr name="holo_blue_dark" format="color"/>
```

**res\values\styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="holo_blue_dark">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

**res\values\colors.xml**

```
<color name="your_color">#FF33B5E5</color>
```

And make sure you are using the theme ***AppTheme.Dark*** where you are using that attribute.