# Is it possible to create a resource file that defines drawables?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable

I'd like to have an xml file similar to strings.xml, where I can name drawable resources. For example, it might look something like this.

```
<resources>
    <drawable name="app_icon">android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon</drawable>
    <drawable name="share_icon">android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share</drawable>
</resources>
```

This way if I want to change an icon, I know right where to look and don't have to search through the code.

Comment: reference in theme ? (define attribute, set it in theme, use whenever you want) similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994091/how-to-reference-colour-attribute-in-drawable#15993560)  omit first point

Comment: I think Themes come handy here!