# Drawable resources referencing attributes

Tags: android, android-theme

I have the following problem:

My app has a light and a dark theme and I'm trying to apply touch feedback to some custom views for both above and below v21 (ripple touch feedback). I've created two drawable resources in `drawable-v21` for a toggle button, one for light and one for dark:

Dark:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/color_control_highlight_default">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask" android:drawable="@drawable/dark_button_border"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_toggle_states"/>
</ripple>
```

Light:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/color_control_highlight_default">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask" android:drawable="@drawable/light_button_border" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_toggle_states" />
</ripple>
```

As can be seen both resources reference another `drawable` which defines the colours for different states of the buttons:

`button_toggle_states`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/color_primary_1" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="?attr/color_primary_1" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="?attr/color_primary_1" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="?attr/button_border" />
</selector>
```

This `drawable` references attributes that change between the light and the dark theme and this is where my problem is. When trying to use this `drawable` I get a runtime error that the `button_toggle_states` in `res/drawable-v21` can't be found. When I change the `drawable` to reference colours and other `drawables` instead of attributes, i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/lt_blue" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/lt_blue" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/lt_blue" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/light_button_border" />
</selector>
```

everything works fine. But with that solution I'll have to make two `button_toggle_state` files, one for dark and one for light theme, while I thought this shouldn't be needed since we can reference attributes in v21 and up.

Is there somethin I'm doing wrong or is referencing attributes in a `drawable` that is used by another `drawable` just not supported?

Answer (score 1):

i ran into the same issue and was not able to get this running. My workaround is to have the drawable itself as a reference in the theme and then have two Drawables: one for light and one for dark.

See also:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251

[How to reference colour attribute in drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994091/how-to-reference-colour-attribute-in-drawable)

Comment: I see, thanks for the link. That issue seems to be about not being able to reference attributes at all in drawables, but for me that's not true since I can reference ?attr/color_control_highlight_default in the ripple resource which works fine...

Comment: Is it pre-21 or post-21?

Comment: This is all for post 21, I have separate resources completely for below 21

Comment: Ok, and you are sure that you have the missing drawable exactly in the -v21 folder?

Comment: Yes completely sure, also since if I change the attribute references to color and drawable references everything works fine.